# Make predict specify bad factor level in R with randomForest

Tags: r

I'm running a `randomForest` model in R with out of sample validation data:

```
predictions <- predict(rf, newdata = model_final, type = "prob")
```

and there's apparently a new factor level somewhere, leading to this message:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(rf, newdata = model_final, type = "prob") : 
  New factor levels not present in the training data
```

Ignoring everything specific to my data and model, is there any way to force `predict` to specify which column(s) are those with the new factor levels? Or is there another, quick, programmatic way to identify the problematic columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the training and the test sets have the same order of columns just use a single mapply to identify where the `factor` levels are not the same:

Example Data

```
training <- data.frame(a=as.factor(letters), b=letters, stringsAsFactors=F)
test     <- data.frame(a=as.factor(rep(letters[1:20],3)), b=rep(letters[1:20],3), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Solution

```
> mapply(function(x,y) identical(levels(x), levels(y)), training, test )
    a     b 
FALSE  TRUE
```

Where the above returns FALSE there is a difference between the levels of the factors between the training and the test set. Since it uses `identical` in cases of numeric, logical or character columns the function `levels` returns NULL in both cases for which `identical` returns TRUE.

Assuming I got what you meant in your question just look for the FALSE columns returned from the above function.